# From builtin ASP.NET membership to custom membership password problem

Tags: asp.net, passwords, membership

We have a production site using ASP.NET built in membership. Now we wan't to extend the tables with some custom properties so we built a custom membership provider using ADO.Net entities.

Everything is working fine, we can create new users and the login controls are also working. We imported every existing user from the aspnet_Membership table into our custom table, and copied the password field into our custom password field in the custom table.

Unfortunately, these existing user cannot login into the system. We found out while debugging the system that the password is not properly decrypted (we're using passwordFormat="Encrypted").

For example:
We have an user with password `testing123`. When we decrypt the password from the database, it returns `睝렱ꀱ꘲䧥꾖饱testing123`

Does anybody have an idea what we're doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** 
I find [this answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1309046.aspx)  where is described you should remove the salt (8 bytes) from your password. In that case that is the solution for me, but then I have a problem with new users passwords which are working OK by default.. Is there no other possibility?

Comment: How are you decrypting the passwords? I was under the impression that it was a one-way encryption.

Comment: Did you copy across the PasswordSalt field?  Password and PasswrordSalt are required to decrypt

Comment: How I tell the custom membershipprovider to decrypt with the passwordSalt?